# Как менять курсор при наведении на строки в QTableView?

Tags: c++, qt, gui, qt4

Как установить другой курсор именно при наведении на любую ячейку/строку в таблице, а не на область всего `QTableView`? Если строк в таблице мало и есть пустое место, то `QTableView::setCursor()` не подходит. Непонятно, как реализовать это и через `eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)` - предположим, я получаю текущую позицию курсора внутри `QTableView`, но как узнать, относится ли эта позиция к контенту или нет? Или возможно установить курсор через `css :hover`? На свойство `cursor` ругается, что такого свойства нет.

Comment: `:hover` устанавливает стиль, когда курсор наведен, а не сам курсор

Comment: @gil9red я имею в виду например такой стиль `QTableView::item:hover { color: red; cursor: pointer }` цвет просто для примера. В классических `CSS` при помощи `:hover` устанавливается стиль (в т.ч. и вид курсора) при наведении на элемент. Поэтому предположил, что здесь должно быть нечто аналогичное.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте [QTableView::indexAt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html#indexAt), чтобы получить по текущим координатам мышки элемент таблицы и проверяйте индекс с помощью `isValid`, и если валидный, меняйте курсор, иначе – возвращайте который по умолчанию